# Proof environment in the svmult class

Tags: sv-classes, proof-package

I'm using the svmult class. If I write

\begin{proof}[Proof of Proposition 1]

what I get is

"Proof(Proof of Proposition 1)"

**How can i get "Proof of Proposition 1" only?**

Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest a new environment modelled on the standard `proof` of `svmult`.

```latex
\documentclass{svmult}

\spnewtheorem*{varproof}{\noexpand\thisproofname}{\itshape}{\rmfamily}
\newcommand{\thisproofname}{} % initialization
\newenvironment{proof*}[1]
  {\renewcommand\thisproofname{#1}\varproof}
  {\endvarproof}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
This is a standard proof
\end{proof}

\begin{proof*}{Proof of proposition 1}
A titled proof.
\end{proof*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot!